# How to fix up this blurry part?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, logo

I am making a logo for my site and for that i tried working on photoshop with a very small screen (136 x 54 px) with 300px/inch 
However its getting really blurry at this point . [image: Here] This is the sample .

Any suggestion how to improve the quality ?

P.S-  I am a newbie in designing so pardon me for any error/mistake.

Comment: Is it live type, a shape layer, a smart object layer.... or is it just a raster image of type? Have you looked into the anti-alias settings if it's live type? Are you zooming in? 136px will only look good at 100% if you zoom in, you're always going to see some "blurring".

Comment: its just a raster image

Comment: YOur posted image is 656 px x 260 px You cannot zoom a raster image by 4x and then evaluate/complain about its quality based on that size. The only preview you use and evaluate should should be 136 x 54 px viewed at 100% pixel size.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are seeing is not "blurring". It's called antialiasing.

Antialiasing is a method of stopping fonts looking jagged when viewed at 100%. When you zoom in on text more than 100% you will begin to see the pixels, and you can clearly see the antialiasing.

It can be switched off in Photoshop, however when viewed at 100% the text will no longer look smooth. To switch off antialiasing, in the tool options of the Text Tool, change the antialiasing setting to "none".

[image: Example of antialiased text versus no antialiasing]

In the top example you can see antialiased text zoomed in and at 100%. The text at 100% looks sharp and the letter X is smooth. Below that you can see an example of text with antialising off, with the text at 100% you can clearly see the letter X has jagged pixels.

Answer (score 1):

You can take the Pencil tool and edit your antialiased image pixel by pixel into a good shape. In pixel dimensions this low that's not much work.

Anti-aliasing is the standard method to get good average appearance when for example something is scaled to smaller size. Unfortunately it makes the editing difficult.